# Return singleton/object from method

Tags: scala, singleton-type, scala-2.12

How can I make this work?

```
  def getSingleton[T <: scala.Singleton]: T = {
     ???
  }

  object X

  val x = getSingleton[X.type]
```

Or similar, appreciate the signature may need to change slightly.

Comment: This already exists, is called `valueOf`, and uses the `ValueOf` type class: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/ValueOf.html

Comment: Ah that would have been amazing, but I'm stuck on 2.12 which doesn't have that type class. How to do it in 2.12?

Comment: Ah, sadly I think you need to use the `Witnees` thing from **Shapeless** or re-implement it yourself _(it is a macro)_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Scala 2.13 there is built-in type class `ValueOf` [1](https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/v2.13.0) [2](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5310) [3](https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/42.type.html)

```
def getSingleton[T <: Singleton](implicit valueOf: ValueOf[T]): T = valueOf.value
```

In Scala 2.12 you can use type class `Witness` from Shapeless [1](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#singleton-typed-literals) [2](https://books.underscore.io/shapeless-guide/shapeless-guide.html#literal-types)

```
// libraryDependencies += "com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.3.10"
import shapeless.Witness

def getSingleton[T <: Singleton](implicit witness: Witness.Aux[T]): T = witness.value
```

Or if you prefer not to depend on Shapeless you can write a [macro](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html)

```
// libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

def getSingleton[T <: Singleton]: T = macro getSingletonImpl[T]

def getSingletonImpl[T <: Singleton : c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  // q"${weakTypeOf[T].typeSymbol.name.toTermName}"
  // q"${weakTypeOf[T].dealias.typeSymbol.asClass.module}" // dealiased version
  q"${symbolOf[T].asClass.module}"                     // not dealiased version
}
```

All the above works at compile time. If it's enough to get the value at runtime you can use Scala [runtime reflection](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html) with `TypeTag`

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => rm}
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def getSingleton[T: TypeTag]: T =
  rm.reflectModule(symbolOf[T].asClass.module.asModule).instance.asInstanceOf[T]
```

or with `ClassTag`

```
import scala.reflect.{ClassTag, classTag}

def getSingleton[T: ClassTag]: T =
  rm.reflectModule(rm.moduleSymbol(classTag[T].runtimeClass)).instance.asInstanceOf[T]
```

or if you prefer not to depend on `scala-reflect` you can use Java reflection

```
def getSingleton[T: ClassTag]: T =
  classTag[T].runtimeClass.getField("MODULE$").get(null).asInstanceOf[T]
```

[In scala, is it possible to initialise a singleton object from a TypeTag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67353632/in-scala-is-it-possible-to-initialise-a-singleton-object-from-a-typetag)

[Get the module symbol, given I have the module class, scala macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64121612/get-the-module-symbol-given-i-have-the-module-class-scala-macro)

[Get instance of singleton type in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54786083/get-instance-of-singleton-type-in-scala)

[Scala object import in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47312104/scala-object-import-in-runtime)